# VueJS Bootstrap <date-picker> is hidden in <b-table> row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using VueJS (v2.6.10) and boostrap-vue (v2.0) and trying to allow users to enter a datetime for a record in a `<b-table>` using the using vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker (v5.0.1).

The issue is that the `<date-picker>` is always hidden when the input field is clicked.  What is a proper way to allow a user to select a date/time for an input field in a `<b-table>` row (if any)?

```
<b-table bordered :items="items" :fields="visibleFields">
...
    <template slot="next_scheduled_time" slot-scope="row">
      <div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; position: relative;" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <date-picker style="width:140px" v-model="row.item.next_scheduled_time" :config="datetime_options" :placeholder="row.item.next_scheduled_time"/>
      </div>
    </template>
...
</b-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect slot syntax.  Correct syntax is seen [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots) in the Bootstrap Vue documentation for b-table.

> Scoped field slots use the following naming syntax: 'cell(' + field key + ')'

Given a field `next_scheduled_time` the slot would be:

```html
<template #cell(next_scheduled_time)="data">
  <div
    style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; position: relative"
    class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
  >
    <date-picker
      v-model="data.item.next_scheduled_time"
      :config="options"
    ></date-picker>
  </div>
</template>
```

The above code works ok when I test inside a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-babbage-p7h5yh?file=/App.vue)

Comment: thanks @yoduh, this pointed me in the right direction to just see it work...the slot syntax I'm using is older, but works for my version of vue/bootstrap...I found a CSS issue that was the culprit...

Answer (score 0):

an improperly scoped  block with this CSS in another vue file was the issue...

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```